# div nested in div not clickable

Tags: html, css

I have one notification css. Unfortunately, have for one wrap body of the notification.

This wrap always shows on all pages, but if the notification is closed, the block is active and it gets impossible to click anything on the site.

```
.notice-wrap {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I could not find a better solution for wrapping the div with full width and responsive, only for width and height set 100%.

I need full width and height, because in the `.notice-wrap` I have one div for `.notice-item-wrapper` which has `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);`.

But if `.notice-wrap` is not full width and height, the bg color is not full width either.

How can I click a div underneath another div?

I tried `display:inline-block` for `.notice-wrap`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you provide the full code?

Comment: Your problem is most likely caused by z-index stacking order. We need to see more code.

Comment: Full code: https://gist.github.com/EverThems/eb625750839f5985b35610bfa0341c72

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think overlapping every page with a full-page div is not a good idea, but adding `pointer-events: none` to its style will make the elements beneath it clickable.

**This WILL NOT work on IE<11**

```
.notice-wrap {
   pointer-events: none;
   display: block;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0px;
   z-index: 9999;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you soo much!

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code. Change your height to the height of the notice div. ex: `height:90px`. You've essentially created a full height and full width div, that sits on top of everything because of your z-index, which would make everything underneath unable to be clicked.

Comment: If i change height 90px, only have 90px block for black background displaying. But i need the fully.